# Convert UTC Milliseconds to DATETIME in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2005, utc

I want to convert UTC milliseconds to DateTime in SQL server.

This can easily be done in C# by following code:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds(1348203320000);
```

I need to do this in SQL server. I found some script [here](http://extendeddotnet.blogspot.in/2011/10/convert-net-datetimeticks-to-t-sql.html), but this was taking initial ticks from 1900-01-01.

I have used the `DATEADD` function as below, but this was giving an arithmetic overflow exception by supping milliseconds as difference:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND,1348203320000,'1970-1-1')
```

How can I do the conversion properly?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
DECLARE @UTC BIGINT
SET @UTC = 1348203320997 

SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND, @UTC % 1000, DATEADD(SECOND, @UTC / 1000, '19700101'))
```

Comment: fails for value 3429993600000 with "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.". Checked on SQL Server 2019 latest CU.

Comment: @Oleksandr It is because the parameter to dateadd is an integer. It would be so much easier if dateadd could take a bigint as parameter. Vote for it here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/37801321-dateadd-big

Comment: @Oleksandr `select dateadd(millisecond, @UTC % 86400000,  dateadd(day, @UTC / 86400000, '19700101'));`

Answer (score 5):

Below the function that converts milliseconds to datetime

```
IF object_id('dbo.toDbTimeMSC', 'FN') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION dbo.toDbTimeMSC
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[toDbTimeMSC] (@unixTimeMSC BIGINT) RETURNS DATETIME
BEGIN
    RETURN DATEADD(MILLISECOND, @unixTimeMSC % 1000, DATEADD(SECOND, @unixTimeMSC / 1000, '19700101'))
END
GO
```

-- select dbo.toDbTimeMSC(1348203320000)

Answer (score 4):

Using SQL Server 2008R2 this produced the required result:

```
CAST(SWITCHOFFSET(CAST(dateadd(s, convert(bigint, [t_stamp]) / 1000, convert(datetime, '1-1-1970 00:00:00')) AS DATETIMEOFFSET), DATENAME (TZoffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())) AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 3):

I had problems with using answers given here (especially that the system was counting ticks form 0001-01-01) - so I did this:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME,[Time]/ 10000.0/1000/86400-693595)

--explanation for [Time_in_Ticks]/ 10000.0/1000/86400-693595
--Time is in "ticks"
--10000 = number of ticks in Milisecond
--1000  = number of milisecons in second
--86400 = number of seconds in a day (24hours*60minutes*60second)
--693595= number of days between 0001-01-01 and 1900-01-01 (which is base
--          date when converting from int to datetime)
```

Comment: All the other answers on this page fail due to the number being too big.   The number is [638106300000000000] which is 29th Jan 2023. SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,638106300000000000/ 10000.0/1000/86400-693595)
 works perfectly.  THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 2):

The `DATEADD` requires an integer as a second argument. Your number `1348203320000` is very large for integer therefore it produce an error in runtime. Your should use `bigint` type instead and provide DATEADD with correct int values by splitting your milliseconds to  seconds and milliseconds. That is sample you could use.

```
DECLARE @total bigint = 1348203320000;

DECLARE @seconds int = @total / 1000
DECLARE @milliseconds int = @total % 1000;

DECLARE @result datetime = '1970-1-1';
SET @result = DATEADD(SECOND, @seconds,@result);
SET @result = DATEADD(MILLISECOND, @milliseconds,@result);
SELECT @result
```

Comment: This also fails due to the number being too big.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you can use dateadd with division on minutes and not seconds.

The code will be like this:

`DATEADD(MILLISECOND, epoch% 60000, DATEADD(MINUTE, epoch/ 60000, '19700101'));`

Answer (score 0):

```
=dateadd("d",INT((Fields!lastLogon.Value / 864000000000)- 134774),"1970-01-01 00:00:00")
```

That's what I used in SSRS to get around the INT error, use days instead of seconds. Is it wrong?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30879184)