# MSSQL - Convert milliseconds since 1970 to datetime2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

Consider the following query (in MSSQL 2008):

```
SELECT dateModified FROM SomeTable;
```

This returns floats in javascript format (milliseconds since 1970):

```
dateModified 
============ 
1301598290687 
1071003581343 
1311951478593
```

How can I convert this to a datetime2 right in the select?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the formula from [@Mikeal Eriksson's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524537/convert-utc-milliseconds-to-datetime-in-sql-server/12524691#12524691).

I would convert the float to a bigint and then create the datetime:

```
select 
  DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 
          cast(dateModified as bigint) % 1000, 
          DATEADD(SECOND, cast(dateModified as bigint) / 1000, '19700101'))
from sometable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed339/3)

Answer (score -1):

Some Oracle example - replace to_date() with eqivalent:

```
  SELECT (1301598290687/60/60/24/1000) as Days
   , to_date('01-01-1970','dd-mm-yyyy') as start_date
   , to_date('01-01-1970','dd-mm-yyyy')+(1301598290687/60/60/24/1000) as converted_date
  FROM dual
  /

DAYS                START_DATE      CONVERTED_DATE
---------------------------------------------------------
15064.7950310995    1/1/1970        3/31/2011 7:04:51 PM
```

Create dual table:

```
CREATE TABLE DUAL
(
DUMMY VARCHAR(1)
)
GO
INSERT INTO DUAL (DUMMY)
 VALUES ('X')
GO
```