# Extract weekday from millisecond in a MSSQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I used the below query to extract the weekday by providing `datetime` that works fine but I need to extract weekday from a Millisecond column

If `TIMEVAL` is `DATETIME` datatype then below one works:

```
SELECT DATEPART(dw,TIMEVAL) FROM Student;
```

If `TIMEVAL` is in `Big Int` (Millisecond) then the same query doesn't work

So, how can I get the WEEKDAY by using *DATEPART* for a column which contains *MILLISECOND*?

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524537/convert-utc-milliseconds-to-datetime-in-sql-server to convert milliseconds to datetime

Comment: I found it here is the query to get the weekday

SELECT DATEPART(dw, (DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()),DATEADD(ss, TIMEVAL/1000,'1970-01-01')))) FROM Student

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for my above question

> SELECT DATEPART(dw, (DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()),dateadd(ss, TIMEVAL/1000,'1970-01-01')))) FROM Student