# Storing Lap Times SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Whats the best solution to store lap times on a SQL-Server database? the suggested format should be `01:52.525`. I'm using time(3) but it does not allow me to use the `Avg()` Function.

Best regards,

Comment: Could you give us more detail from your question?Provide some sample data and expect result .that really help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already storing the lap duration as `time`, you can use `DATEDIFF` to calculate duration in milliseconds for the average calc and use `DATEADD` to convert milliseconds to time.

```
SELECT 
      AVG(DATEDIFF(millisecond, '', LapTime)) AS AvgLapTimeMilliseconds
    , CAST(DATEADD(millisecond, AVG(DATEDIFF(millisecond, '', LapTime)), '') AS time(3)) AS AvgLapTime
FROM dbo.Lap;
```

Comment: @Lamag, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the start time and duration (lap time) in epoch milliseconds, then use a SQL query (which would allow `Avg()`):

```
SELECT (duration - start) FROM lap_times (WHERE ...)
```

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524537/convert-utc-milliseconds-to-datetime-in-sql-server) for converting milliseconds to a human-readable timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Store the times as `time`.  Add computed columns with the values as milliseconds.  Use the computed columns for calculations.

For example:

```
alter table t add laptime_ms as (datediff(ms, 0, laptime));
```

You can now use this for averages, and convert back to time as:

```
select convert(time, dateadd(ms, 0, avg(laptime_ms)))
from t
```